# New to HTML and CSS and I need help optimising my code. Also have a few issues with dynamic sizing of elements

Tags: html, css

Hopefully this is the right sub for me. I am relatively new to HTML and CSS and can tell the way I have done some things are inefficient and silly.

I was wondering if anyone had the time to look through my html and css and optimise things which are redundant or the wrong way of doing them. For example in my CSS, I have 3 different id's with identical properties bar font size and style.

If you have time, I would love help with being able to dynamically resize the image (bb.png) in the `imageAlign` class, and I would love help figuring out why on mobile devices, everything is really small (still in perspective, just too small and not nicely in the middle. Also firefox desktop makes it look weird but I am not too fussed with that at the moment.

Thanks!

**HTML**

```
<body>

    <div id="Absolute-Center">
        <div id="drawbox">

            <div class="imageAlign">
                <img src="bb.png" width="280px" height="130px" alt="logo">
            </div>

            <div id="content1">
                WHERE HOUSE MUSIC MEETS CHARITY
            </div>
            <div id="content2">
                A series of dance parties that raise money for numerous worthy charities. We provide a good time and good music with all proceeds going towards helping those facing far tougher times.
            </div>

            <div id ="content3">
                Full website coming soon. <br>
                For information, updates and enquiries please check out our <a href ="https://www.facebook.com/XXXX"> Facebook</a> page or send us an <a href ="mailto:XXXX@XXX.COM"> email</a>.
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

**CSS**

```
html  {
      overflow: hidden;
}


/* Draw border */
#drawbox { 
    width: 85%;
    padding-bottom: 10%;
    margin-left: auto ;
    margin-right: auto ;
    border-image-slice: 70 64 51 45; 
    border-image-width: 20px 20px 20px 20px; 
    border-image-outset: 0px 0px 0px 0px; 
    border-image-repeat: stretch stretch; 
    border-image-source: url(handdrawn_line.png);
/*

    Make border here: www./developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Tools/Border-image_generator
*/

}


#Absolute-Center {
  width: 50%;
  height: 58%;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 25%; right: 0;
}




#content1 {
  font-family: Adam Warren pro, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  width: 80% ;
  margin-left: auto ;
  margin-right: auto ;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5vw;
  padding-bottom: 20%;
  padding-top: 5%;



}

#content2 {
font-family: 'Kalam', cursive;
  width: 80% ;
  margin-left: auto ;
  margin-right: auto ;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.1vw;
  padding-bottom: 10%;


}

#content3 {
font-family: 'Kalam', cursive;
  width: 80% ;
  margin-left: auto ;
  margin-right: auto ;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.9vw;


}


.imageAlign {
    margin-top: 10%;
    text-align: center;

}
```

Comment: Just a few things. What is the html overflow hidden good for? get rid of that. If you use vw as font size, your fonts scale with windows size. This is why you have small fonts on small devices. Use pt, px or em instead. If you want your image to resize, give it a width via css (100% for example). And if you need help with your code, try to bring it in with a fiddle.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Having those Ids classes with identical code is not efficient: Instead of using #id to style an element, use classes.

Create a class for all the properties that are identical and assign this class to all the HTML elements.

For example, instead of repeating font-family: 'Kalam', cursive;
  width: 80% in several #id create a class ".typography-big" or whatever and then apply the style to all the html elements that wil hace that style (#content2 and #content3).

This way you don't repeat code.

Answer (score 0):

To optimize your code you could do:

good:

```
#ID1, #ID2, #ID3{
margin-left: auto;
}
```

better:

```
.samestyle{
margin-left: auto;
}
```

it's better because: 1. it's shorter, 2. it's easier to change your style as you only need to change an attribute once, as opposed to 3 or 4 times.

for example:

```
font-family: 'Kalam', cursive;
  width: 80% ;
  margin-left: auto ;
  margin-right: auto ;
  text-align: center;
```

this piece of CSS occurs 3 times in your stylesheet, to make things easier you could put them in a class, remove them from the ID and then do as follows:

CSS:

```
.contentClass{
    font-family: 'Kalam', cursive;
      width: 80% ;
      margin-left: auto ;
      margin-right: auto ;
      text-align: center;
```

}

and change your HTML code to:

```
 <div id="content1" class="contentClass">
 WHERE HOUSE MUSIC MEETS CHARITY
 </div>
```

This way you only need to change the styles within the class 'contentClass' just once, instead of three or four times, perhaps more. This way you save time and space allowing you to work more efficiently